# Questions about add firewall exception in wix installer by firewall extension

Tags: exception, windows-7, wix, installation, firewall

I am new to **Wix installer**. I am trying to add **firewall exception** for my program.

### My code is as follow:

```
<Component Id="_VIEW.EXE" Guid="*" Transitive="yes">
     <File Id="view.exe"
           Name="view.exe"
           KeyPath="yes"
           Source="$(var.INSTALLSOURCE)\view.exe">
       <fire:FirewallException Id="view_firewall_domain_tcp"
                               Name="View"
                               Protocol="tcp"
                               Scope="any"
                               IgnoreFailure="yes"
                               Profile="domain" />
       <fire:FirewallException Id="view_firewall_domain_udp"
                               Name="View"
                               Protocol="udp"
                               Scope="any"
                               IgnoreFailure="yes"
                               Profile="domain" />
       <fire:FirewallException Id="view_firewall_private_tcp"
                               Name="View"
                               Protocol="tcp"
                               Scope="any"
                               IgnoreFailure="yes"
                               Profile="private" />
       <fire:FirewallException Id="view_firewall_private_udp"
                               Name="View"
                               Protocol="udp"
                               Scope="any"
                               IgnoreFailure="yes"
                               Profile="private" />
     </File>
  </Component>
```

In my code, I add **4 firewall exception** and each exception has different value for "**Profile**" and "**Protocol**" attributes. My expected result is 4 exceptions created:

```
NAME  GROUP   Profile   Enabled  Action  Override  Program           Local Address   Remote Address   Protocol   Local Port   Remote Port   Allowed Users  Allowed Computers
view          Domain     Yes     Allow    No       c:\test\view.exe    Any               Any            TCP         Any         Any             Any            Any
view          Domain     Yes     Allow    No       c:\test\view.exe    Any               Any            UDP         Any         Any             Any            Any
view          Private    Yes     Allow    No       c:\test\view.exe    Any               Any            TCP         Any         Any             Any            Any
view          Private    Yes     Allow    No       c:\test\view.exe    Any               Any            UDP         Any         Any             Any            Any
```

But the actual result is only one exception is created and the value of "Protocol" attribute is "any" instead of "**TCP**" or "**UDP**":

```
NAME  GROUP   Profile   Enabled  Action  Override  Program           Local Address   Remote Address   Protocol   Local Port   Remote Port   Allowed Users  Allowed Computers
view          Domain     Yes     Allow    No       c:\test\view.exe    Any               Any            Any         Any         Any             Any            Any
```

### So, I have two questions:

1. Why is only one exception created? Must the name of the exception be unique?
2. Why does the value of the "Protocol" attribute not take effect?

I refer an official document about firewall extension:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/firewall/firewallexception.html
In the document, I saw some description about "File" attribute:

> Identifier of a file to be granted access to all incoming ports and protocols. If you use File, you cannot also use Program.
>   If you use File and also Port or Protocol in the same FirewallException element, the exception will fail to install on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. IgnoreFailure="yes" can be used to ignore the resulting failure, but the exception will not be added.

Does it mean that if I set firewall rule for a program, the "Protocol" and "Port" attributes will be "Any" automatically even I set "Protocol"?

Answer (score 3):

The existing wix FirewallException custom actions make use of the XP/Server2003 windows firewall API. In this API, setting a firewall exception for a particular executable implies that all ports and all protocols will be opened to the exception.

For reference, the [XP/Server2003 firewall API interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366449(v=vs.85).aspx). Notice that INetFwOpenPort has the ability to get/set the port, while INetFwAuthorizedApplication does not.

If you want to create a firewall exception on a program and explicitly limit the port, protocol, and domain you'll need to make use of the windows 'advanced' firewall API that came with Vista. Check out these references:
[Highlevel overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754274.aspx)
[Reference guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709)
[Command-line reference guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx)

Sadly, nobody has yet implemented an AdvancedFirewallException extension for wix that makes use of these updated APIs. Maybe I'll run a kickstarter campaign to see if there interest in funding the development ;P

Answer (score 2):

Try to use different Names for each FirewallExeption ID. This worked for me:

```
<File Id="sample.exe"
              Name="sample.exe"
              Source="..\TestFrame\bin\debug\sample.exe"
              Vital="yes"
              KeyPath='yes'>

          <fire:FirewallException Id="FirewallDomainSampleTcp"
                                  Name="Domain Sample TCP"
                                  Protocol="tcp"
                                  Port="8080"
                                  Scope="any"
                                  IgnoreFailure="yes"
                                  Profile="domain" />

          <fire:FirewallException Id="FirewallDomainSampleUdp"
                                  Name="Domain Sample UDP"
                                  Protocol="udp"
                                  Port="8080"
                                  Scope="any"
                                  IgnoreFailure="yes"
                                  Profile="domain" />

          <fire:FirewallException Id="FirewallPrivatSampleTcp"
                                  Name="Private Sample TCP"
                                  Protocol="tcp"
                                  Port="8080"
                                  Scope="any"
                                  IgnoreFailure="yes"
                                  Profile="private" />

          <fire:FirewallException Id="FirewallPrivateSampleUdp"
                                  Name="Private Sample UDP"
                                  Protocol="udp"
                                  Port="8080"
                                  Scope="any"
                                  IgnoreFailure="yes"
                                  Profile="private" />
        </File>
```